# Moving from WebAPI REST to SignalR realtime (for the lazy coder)

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have an ASP.NET app that has a dozen ViewModel-centric WebAPI controllers presenting a RESTful API. Each controller supports a few HTTP methods. All very normal, and AFAIK a pretty clean implementation. The majority of those API methods would benefit greatly from SignalR (or other realtime) integration. For example:

```
public class AppointmentController : BaseApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id) {
        DataServices.AppointmentService.Cancel(id);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This WebAPI tooling:

- does all the routing for me: `Delete(int id)`
- deserializes JSON
- serializes the response `Ok()`
- some other helpful bits with security, etc.

**If I move to SignalR, do I have to take a few step back and now write all that code myself, or am I overlooking some component or concept?**

And it looks like at the AngularJS client I have a similar impedance...

I'm currently using .NET 4.5, but happy to move. And I'm not restricted to SignalR either. I welcome recommendations for other realtime libraries that are more complete and preserve my ASP.NET and EntityFramework investment.

Comment: can u share the reason u would like to move from web api to Signalr. This will help better to discuss whether u should move to signalr or not.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what details you are looking for; isn't the only reason to implement SignalR for allowing near-realtime updates and shared state across multiple clients? I have many types that would benefit from this, especially viewmodel collections that display lists in UIs that are kept open all day, in order to support business decisions. Imagine it as a dashboard if you will. The example I gave above was an appointment list, where a consumer could always view upcoming appointments at a glance. In some cases, editing is also important in the same UI.

Comment: I understand what u r trying to say. And as per ur requirements of real time data update, SignalR is perfect to go for. The only thing that i was wondering was why u had WebAPI initially. So to support ur question, if u want a real time application functionality, then Signalr is the right option in asp.net. The only thing u need to do is (and u may be aware of the same) create a hub, add ur methods into it and call those from the client side. If u need real-time application, u will have to move to Signalr (from web api).

Comment: I was thinking the other day: Could those two exist next to each other in a useful way? Usually I find handling CRUD operations via SignalR rather messy. You could consider sticking to WebAPI and use SignalR notifications to trigger REST operations etc. Not really targetting the question, I know.

Comment: @rdoubleui: Completely agree. Plus I wouldn't have to implement such duplicate security - who gets which records on an aggregate push sounds like a nightmare. Simpler if each record update is requested by a single client that knows if it already holds the record in it's UI, and tests are performed per-record as I've already implemented. However, I has hoped to avoid the "chatter", and just send the packets required. I also was looking for a way to subscribe to individual list requests on SignalR channels based on WebAPI requests. You've probably been assessing the same.

Comment: @TechJay : I initially wrote it as a REST interface because there was so much less impedance between AngularJS and ASP.NET when using WebAPI than SignalR. The feature list I mentioned above (client/server de/serialization, server API security, client/server API-to-http naming/routing conventions, etc.) are the big reasons WebAPI was less effort. The same could potentially exist for SignalR, but it does not, so SignalR is currently more custom code and re-inventing the wheel. I also didn't realize that moving from WebAPI to SignalR would require discarding so much code.